# I am getting this error I want to readfile using javascript code Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFile is not a function. I am getting this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, node-modules, fs

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('analogData.txt', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else console.log(data);
});
```

I am trying to read a text file and by using javascript I want to display the data read by the fs into HTML tag

I am using browserify so that browser can understand that mode modules code.

```
browserify main.js > bundle.js
```

I have used this command to transform module into browser understandable code and I have included ` to include javascript code into index.html

Comment: Browser do not have access to file system, unless the file is selected in file input by user

Answer (score 0):

That API isn't available in the browser. This makes sense if you think about it: where would the browser load the file from?

Comment: The browser will load files from the same directory in which index.html is located.

Comment: Browsers are designed to run on client machines separate from the server. Perhaps you could host the file on your webserver and use XHR or fetch to download it?